# rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py

Tags: ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

runnig the above command returns tf2_tools not found. What could be the reason?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261128/rosrun-tf2_tools-view_frames.py/) by [auxisan](https://answers.ros.org/users/30267/auxisan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please read through http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do to get an idea of what info you better provide.

Also your case, a package in question not found, is FAQ. You can [find other threads](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=site%3Aros.org+package+not+found&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) where you can get many hints.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [apanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/29296/apanda/) on 2017-05-31**:
also i met this problem:
env: ubuntu 14.4 LTS,  ROS indigo.
reproduce step: rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py(provided by http://wiki.ros.org/tf2_tools)
result :tf2_tools not found

try to install like this:sudo apt-get install tf2-tools
return can not find tf2-tools

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2017-05-31**:
@apanda please open a new question; comment section is NOT designed for asking your own question (most importantly comments don't get as much attention). If your issue is similar to existing thread content then reference from your thread to the relevant threads.